# Why am I prompted to enter username and password when using `salt -a pam`?

Tags: salt-stack, pam

I am following the external authentication documentation at https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/eauth/index.html

I have configured `external_auth` in the master to allow the user `ubuntu` to issue salt commands.

Running `salt -a pam '*' test.ping` as user `ubuntu` works, except I am being prompted for user and password.

I know the about `-T` authentication token option, but it still requires the initial password prompt and it expires.

The command is being executed as `ubuntu` already, why am I being prompted again? Is there a way to remove the prompt altogether? Allowing unattended programs running as the `ubuntu` user to issue salt commands?

Is this a problem with Saltstack, or a matter of pam configuration? According to the documentation Saltstack uses the `login` service (e.g. `/etc/pam.d/login`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/cli/salt.html#cmdoption-salt-a) it's stated: "Pass in an external authentication medium to validate against. The credentials will be prompted for. ", so it's expected.

If you're logged on the master, you shouldn't have to use `external_auth`.

You should instead use `publisher_acl`:

"The salt publisher ACL system is a means to allow system users other than root to have access to execute select salt commands on minions from the master."

See the [docs](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/publisheracl.html) for more infos.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I wasn't aware of `publisher_acl`, I thought `external_auth` would do what I wanted when I found it.